# How do you set the system (or user) timezone in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

It seems that Snowflake defaults to some Pacific timezone. I'd like to use EET as the default time zone. Is there a way to set it system-wide or per user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you're able to set the default timezone for the account with `ACCOUNTADMIN` role with `alter account`:

```
show parameters like 'TIMEZONE%' in account;
alter account set timezone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
show parameters like 'TIMEZONE%' in account;
```

A full list of timezones can be found from [time zone list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

The time zone can also be set per user (`ALTER USER`) or per current session (`ALTER SESSION`) as mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html).

Comment: You can also set it per user or per current session, see the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html

Comment: Thanks, added that to the answer.